# error database connection MMA 12.2

Tags: databaselink, databases

I work with MMA 12.0. When I want to make a connection with met Oracle Database, I do:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
Needs["JLink`"]
$connection = 
 OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["Oracle", "localhost:1521/xxxx"], 
  "Username" -> "xxxxxx", "Password" -> "xxxxxx"]
```

After this I can query my Oracle dbase like

```
SQLExecute[$connection, "select * from tablename"];
```

Everythin works fine.
Now I installed MMA 12.2. When I use the same script on the same computer I get a error like:

> KeyExistsQ::invrl: The argument Association[Flatten[JDBCDrivers[]/.
> JDBCDriver[Name->DatabaseLink`SQL`Private`name_,Driver->DatabaseLink`SQL`Private`driver_,Protocol->DatabaseLink`SQL`Private`protocol_,_,_,_]:>{DatabaseLink`SQL`Private`name->Association[Rule[<<2>>],Rule[<<2>>]]}]]
> is not a valid Association or a list of rules.
>
> JDBC::classnotfound: Oracle

Is there a easy way to fix this issue without 'disturbing'the settings of MMA 12.0

Comment: This sounds like a bug, you should report it to Wolfram Research.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240885